# Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this question may have been asked before. But I am having problems resolving it. Can someone please help me understand this error in this specific usecase? Whenever I try to use declare the variables at the top and use a sub query. I am not sure how the values are assigned to the variables in this specific use case.

```
   USE [HRCMS]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getRSUVestingGrantDataForReport]
    @key varchar(50),
    @Emplid VARCHAR(6),
    @AwardPrice varchar(50)
    
    
    
    AS
    BEGIN
    
            DECLARE @ParticipantName varchar(50),       
            @AwardValue varchar(50),    
            @NumberofRSU varchar(50);
        SELECT 
    
            @ParticipantName = convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,Name)),    
            @AwardValue = CONVERT(NUMERIC, ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,RSU_Deferred_Cash_USD)),0)) 
            + CONVERT(NUMERIC,ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,Discretionary_SICP_Deferred)),0)) * ER.Exchange_Rate ,       
            @NumberofRSU = 
            convert(decimal(18,3),
            convert(decimal(18,3),
            CONVERT(decimal(18,3), ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,Discretionary_SICP_Deferred)),0)) * ER.Exchange_Rate +
            CONVERT(decimal(18,3), ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,RSU_Deferred_Cash_USD)),0)))
            /
            CONVERT(decimal(18,3), ISNULL(@AwardPrice,0)))
            --convert(NUMERIC,CONVERT(NUMERIC, ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,RSU_Deferred_Cash_USD)),0))/ CONVERT(NUMERIC, ISNULL(1,0)))
        FROM 
        COMP_REC_ENC    CRE
        Inner Join [dbo].[Exchange_Rates] ER On convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,CRE.Local_Currency_Code)) = ER.Currency_Code and CRE.Year = ER.Year
        Where CRE.[YEAR] = dbo.getCurrentYear() AND convert(VARCHAR(500),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@key,Award_Type)) ='RSU' 
        AND EMPLID = @Emplid
        UNION
            SELECT
        UID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtHeader'        THEN VALUE END) AS txtHeader,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtHeaderNote' THEN VALUE END) AS txtHeaderNote,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtAwardValue'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtAwardValue,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtPerformancePeriod'    THEN VALUE END) AS txtPerformancePeriod,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtScheduledVesting' THEN VALUE END) AS txtScheduledVesting,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtDividendEquivalents'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtDividendEquivalents,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtPaymentDate'        THEN VALUE END) AS txtPaymentDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtTerminationReason1' THEN VALUE END) AS txtTerminationReason1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtUnvestedRSU1'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtUnvestedRSU1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtUnvestedRSU2'        THEN VALUE END) AS txtUnvestedRSU2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtTerminationReason2' THEN VALUE END) AS txtTerminationReason2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtUnvestedRSU3'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtUnvestedRSU3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtUnvestedRSU4'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtUnvestedRSU4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtTerminationReason3'        THEN VALUE END) AS txtTerminationReason3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtTerminationReason4' THEN VALUE END) AS txtTerminationReason4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtNonCompetition'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtNonCompetition,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtNonSolicitation'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtNonSolicitation,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtInteraction'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtInteraction,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtCancellation'        THEN VALUE END) AS txtCancellation,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtRegRequirement' THEN VALUE END) AS txtRegRequirement,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtFootNote'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtFootNote,
        MAX(CASE WHEN "KEY" = 'txtFooter'       THEN VALUE END) AS txtFooter
    
    
    FROM COMP_STATEMENT
        WHERE UID = 6
    GROUP BY
        UID
    
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
  SELECT @a = a
  FROM x
  UNION
  SELECT b
  FROM y
```

You'll have to do this:

```
SELECT
  @a = zz.z
FROM
(
  SELECT a as z
  FROM x
  UNION
  SELECT b
  FROM y
) zz
```

The aliases aren't important.. I just put them there to draw clear distinction between values, and show what is being assigned

Think about this carefully though.. If the union query returns multiple rows, do you know which one you'll get? The variable can only hold one of the row values. It might be better to do e.g. `@a = MAX(zz.z)` so you know for sure you'll get the highest value, or the lowest value... Or craft your subquery so that it certainly only returns one row

---

Per the comment:

You're misunderstanding UNION. The first query defines the column names:

```
SELECT 1 as x UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3

x
----
1
2
3
```

One column, called x, 3 rows. As I said, you can only assign one value to a variable (unless your variable is a table). No programming language I know will let you declare one string variable and assign two values to it, which is exactly what you're trying to do with

```
SELECT @a = n FROM (SELECT 'Jeffrey' as n UNION SELECT 'Caius')
```

The result of the union subquery is a *set of two rows*, your name and mine.You'll have to guess at which one will end up in the `@a` variable - and it really is a guess. It's probably the last one in the result set, whatever order the DB feels like giving the results in today

If you want to catch all the rows you make a [table variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or put them to a temp table

Comment: what is the zz at the bottom represent?

Comment: zz is table alias name

Comment: Every subquery in SQLServer has to have an alias

Comment: How do I get b to show up though? Won't only @a = zz.z show up in this query? My goal is to pull everything.